# Factory pattern in javascript problem with module and class giving me ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

Hello i am using some module behavior and it ask me a question.

```
in one.js :

import { Two } from './two.mjs';

export class One extends Two<<<ReferenceError { 

}
```

```
in two.js :

import { One } from './one.mjs';

export class Two {
    constructor() {
        let one = new One();
    }
}
```

Ok it's not a casual case and it's not really my code but i have simplified.
I know why this error append (the interpreter go in file two then import the file one and in the file one the class Two is not initisialized)
But the question is : How can i find (like in java) a way to avoid this (use only one file, avoid class, idk). Give me your opinion.

Thx a lot.

Comment: So you know what the issue is and how to fix it, but you're wondering how you can combine them into one file?

Comment: No i ask the question (how to use it in a correct way) because using one file is not a good thing usually

Comment: Sorry, so just to clarify. The reference error is because you're calling `new One()` inside of **two.js** and extending `One` from `Two`. Your code makes Class `Two`  need  Class `One` to exist, and Class `One` need Class `Two` to exist.